# A tourist place can have multiple themes. How to implement this in django models?

Tags: python, django

This is my current django models . How can I store multiple Themes for a place name 
Themes are like adventure , beaches , heritage , hill stations etc
A place can be both under adventure , beaches

```
from django.db import models

class places(models.Model):

    place_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    place_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    theme = models.ForeignKey('Theme',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Theme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Comment: The ForeignKey should be on Theme pointing to Place.

Comment: I think it should be ManyToMany on Theme, rather than foreignkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a ManytoManyField.

```
from django.db import models

class Theme(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

        def __str__(self):
           return self.name


class Place(models.Model):

    place_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    place_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    themes = models.ManyToManyField(Theme)
```

[Read the docs here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) Always put the ManytoManyField on the object that will be edited by the form. Also, make sure to initialize the *Theme* class before *Place* so you don't have an undefined error.